# Express, body-parser not parsing form data + object (using Angular.js $recourse)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, parsing, express, body-parser

I'm learning angular.js $resource. As in example in docs I have custom method

```
// some stuff
  {charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}} //declaring custom method
// some stuff
// and then call the this method
card.$charge({amount:9.99});
// It makes POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
```

***The problem is*** that my express app parses only object, and misses `amount=9.99&charge=true`. But if I send only `amount=9.99&charge=true` wihtout object (not via angular's $resource) it parses fine. Same if I send only object. But not both. 
So I can't get `charge=true` which is really necessery. I may even not get object but Angular's $recourse attaches it by default, so I don't know how to prevent attaching object when I call custom method

I'm using: 
**express 4**, **body-parser** with configuration:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
```

and **multer**

So, dear community please HELP. I'm breaking my head for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your $resource declaration,

```
card.$charge({amount:9.99});
```

This will send a POST request with a query : `amount=9.99&charge=true` , to access those in express use `req.query.amount` and `req.query.charge`.